# How to mulitply the user entered arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

im making a program the asks the user to enter the length of the array, and then asks the elements of the array. My question is how do i mulitply these elements? for example:
What is the length of the array?: 4
What are the elements of the array?: 3 6 4 7
the multiplication of {3 6 4 7} is 504.
here is my code so far:

```
     Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("The length of your array is: ");
     int length = s.nextInt();
     int [] myArray = new int [length];
     System.out.println("The elements of your array are: ");

     for(int i=0; i<length; i++ ) {
        myArray[i] = s.nextInt();
     }

     System.out.printf("The multiplication of {%s} is ",Arrays.toString(myArray));

  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: loop and multiply? There is no built-in function for that

Comment: so i should use recursion for the program instead?

Comment: Why not something like `const arrProd = arr => arr.reduce((a,b) => a * b, 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("The length of your array is: ");
    int length = s.nextInt();    
    System.out.println("The elements of your array are: ");
long product = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      product *= s.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.printf("The multiplication of {%s} is ", product);
```

updated your code with a slight tweak

## Alternate using lambda:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList();
System.out.println("The length of your array is: ");
int length = s.nextInt();    
System.out.println("The elements of your array are: ");


numbers = IntStream.range(0, length)
.mapToObj(i -> Integer.valueOf(s.nextInt()))
.collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.printf("The multiplication of {%s} is {%s}",numbers, 
numbers.parallelStream()
.reduce(1, 
(number, product) -> product * number));
```

Comment: is there a way to display the elements of the array in the system.out.printf?

Comment: you could save input to array and print the list in the end. I have added an alternate using lambda too,